# Finding $E(XY)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are dependent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

$X$ and $Y$ are defined on $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$ (we have a discrete uniform distribution) where $$X(\omega)=\begin{cases}1, \text{ if } \omega \text{ even} \\ 0, \text{ else}\end{cases} \text{ and }Y(\omega)=\begin{cases}1, \text{ if } \omega =2 \\ 0, \text{ else}\end{cases}$$ They are dependent. I'm trying to find $E(XY)$. Here's what I got:$$E(XY)=\sum \limits_{\omega\in \Omega}X(\omega)Y(\omega)P(XY=\omega)=1\cdot P(XY=2)=0$$ However, in my book it says $E(XY)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1+\frac{3}{4}\cdot 0=\frac{1}{4}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are only two possible outcomes for $X(\omega)Y(\omega)$, $0$ and $1$. The probability that the outcome is $1$ is $\frac{1}{4}$, since this only occurs when $\omega = 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be doing
$
\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} X(\omega)Y(\omega)P(\omega)
$

This should leave you with
$
0*0*\frac{1}{4}+1*1*\frac{1}{4}+0*0*\frac{1}{4}+1*0*\frac{1}{4}
$
where the summands correspond to $w = 1, 2, 3, 4$ respectively.

Comment: Ah, I see!!! Thank you, Pablo.

Comment: @Analysis As a sidenote, writing $XY=\omega$ makes no sense, beacause $\omega$ is in the domain of $X$ and $Y$, not in their image.